# Heroku with GoDaddy domain not woking

Tags: heroku, dns

**What I would like**

visting efkhunt.com or www.efkhunt.com to be forwarded to my heroku blog at https://efkhunt.herokuapp.com/

I currently have the free version, but happy to upgrade to hobby if it helps avoid SSL errors etc.

**What I've experienced**

Currently : efkhunt.com redirs to http://classical-orangutan-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.herokudns.com/

www.efkhunt.com gives :

*This site can’t provide a secure connection www.efkhunt.com sent an invalid response.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR*

**What I've tried**

I've tried a number of different tutorials, some of which seem contradictory, or perhaps more likely I've not understood them properly. The GD settings I have currently are :

**Type**    **Name**    **Value**   **TTL**

A   @   184.168.131.xxx 600 seconds

CNAME   www thermal-centipede-xxxxx.herokudns.com   1 Hour

CNAME   _domainconnect  _domainconnect.gd.domaincontrol.com 1 Hour

NS  @   ns47.domaincontrol.com  1

NS  @   ns48.domaincontrol.com  1

SOA @   Primary nameserver: ns47.domaincontrol.com. 1

I've been doing this over a number of days so I don't think I should have to wait for any further propagation.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling - I think the browser cache was misleading, there was actually an SSL error which was resolved by turning on automated certificate management, which required to upgrade to a hobby dyno.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management